# Format decimal number with custom amount of digits after comma

Tags: c#, decimal

I have this custom extension that should format a decimal number with a custom amount of digits after comma.

```
public static decimal FormatDecimal(this decimal value, int decimalSeparator = 2)
{
    decimal returnValue = Math.Round(value, decimalSeparator, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
    return returnValue;
}
```

The problem is that doesn't work as expected.

If I do like this:

```
decimal number = 12345;
```

and then:

```
decimal formatedNumber = number.FormatDecimal(2);
```

the result should be:

```
12345.00
```

instead the result is:

```
12345
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `12345` and `12345.00` are equal as a numeric value. How do you display your decimal value exactly? Looks like a _textual_ representation issue.

Comment: @SonerGönül: I just have it .ToString(). However, if the return value is `12345.44` then .ToString() shows it correctly. Except if it's `.00`

Comment: `number.ToString("#.00")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the extension function working

```
    public static string FormatDecimal(this decimal value, int decimalSeparator = 2)
    {
        return  value.ToString(string.Format("0.{0}", new string('0', decimalSeparator)));
    }
```

Comment: This works perfect. However I have one question: If the value is decimal value is 0 this returns `.00`. How can I make it so that returns `0.00` ?

Comment: substitute "#.{0}" with "0.{0}"  (I'll do it in the answer too :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the right way is to using [The `"0"` custom format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#Specifier0);

> Replaces the zero with the corresponding digit if one is present;
>   otherwise, zero appears in the result string.

For example;

```
decimal d = 12345;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("#.00")); // 12345.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking to format the string representation of your decimal instead.  Try this:

```
decimal myNumber = 12345.67m;
string formattedNumber = myNumber.ToString("N3");
Console.WriteLine(formattedNumber); // Prints "12345.670"
```

See here for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

From MSDN:

> Standard numeric format strings are used to format common numeric types. A standard numeric format string takes the form Axx, where:
>
> A is a single alphabetic character called the format specifier. Any numeric format string that contains more than one alphabetic character, including white space, is interpreted as a custom numeric format string. For more information, see Custom Numeric Format Strings.
>
> xx is an optional integer called the precision specifier. The precision specifier ranges from 0 to 99 and affects the number of digits in the result. Note that the precision specifier controls the number of digits in the string representation of a number. It does not round the number itself. To perform a rounding operation, use the Math.Ceiling, Math.Floor, or Math.Round method.
>
> When precision specifier controls the number of fractional digits in the result string, the result strings reflect numbers that are rounded away from zero (that is, using MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).

Comment: I don't think using `N` format specifier is the right way in this case because it formats your value with group separator as well. That's why it will be like `12,345` instead of `12345`.

Comment: Good point.  I personally consider that to be a nice extra feature, but I guess not everyone will feel the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the formatting when you display the string.

What you need is to do the following, when you convert to string:

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", formatedNumber);
```

Refer to [This article](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/) for more details: